# Error Connecting to SQL Sever ->Setting AD ID user for connecting to SQL server using mqsisetdbparams for broker running on linux

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dsn, messagebroker, broker

I have a requirement of configuring the broker with AD id and password to connect to SQL database server .

The commands what I entered for setting up is given below :

1. First I created DSN
2. stopped the broker
3. executed :

   ```
   mqsisetdbparams BROKERNAME -n SQL_ASDA_TMS -u UK\\sqltmsdb -p wmbdev
   ```
4. started the broker

After setting the above property and restarting the broker I tried to validate the connectivity using mqsicvp command which eventually failed and the error was logged in SQL Server as

> login failed for user 'UK\sqltmsdb' .Reason:Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL server authentication .

Find my DSN details below :

```
;# UNIX to SQLServer stanza 
[SQL_ASDA_TMS] 
Driver=/opt/IBM/mqsi/7.0/ODBC/V6.0/lib/UKmsss24.so 
Description=DataDirect 6.0 SQL Server Wire Protocol 
Address=LABUKNTS5028.uk.wal-mart.com,14481 
AnsiNPW=Yes 
Database=TMS 
Trusted_Connection=Yes 
QuotedId=No 
ColumnSizeAsCharacter=1 
LoginTimeout=0
```

Note:

- Broker is running on linux .
- The windows application is able to connect to SQL server using that AD Id
- Broker is able to connect to the same SQL server using normal SQL id and password and failing with AD (active directory) Id

Can somebody help me in telling whether whatever I am trying to implement is possible or not ? 
If yes could you please help me what should I be doing to resolve this issue and if I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication for your DB means, you don't need a user id and password to connect to the database if you are logged in to the windows machine with the corresponding user id.

"User id" in **`mqsisetdbparams`** is treated as a database user id and password and hence giving your Active directory's user id and password in the command will be wrong.

So, in short, an ODBC connection will not be possible from the broker to your database using windows authentication.

But, you always have the option of using the **`JDBC connection`**. This should work even with windows authentication as it doesn't mandate you to give user id and password.

You can use the JDBC connection via a java compute node in your message flow([reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30494_.htm)).

[**Here**](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/08/java-connect-ms-sql-server-using-windows-authentication/) you can find how to use windows authentication for a JDBC connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the difference .
Appreciate it

Comment: You may consider accepting my reply as answer to the question.